# Jquery - Find my required Fields in my visible Fieldsets and show message

Tags: jquery

I want to **find all the required fields** on my form that are **within** a fieldset that is **currently visible**.  I will actually use this code when the user submits the form, but for testing I am using a simple button to check for visible fieldset, then for the fields within those visible fieldset that are required [**noted by the class name ending with -required**].  These fields can be textboxes, radios, checkboxes, etc.  Then determine if they are empty.  If empty provide message in my div telling user which fields are not complete.
I thought I had this code figured out with help from another stackOverflower, but it just does not work in my code.  Could anyone provide some insight please?

**my fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/jVktq/

**My html here:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="holdErrMsg"></div>
    <fieldset id="mainSection" name="mainSection">
                <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Name</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1125" name="1125" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Email</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1026" name="1026" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                        <td><input  id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                        <td><select id="1169" name="1169">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr><td>
                                        <button id="btnCatchReqFlds" type="button" name="btn">Check Required Fields</button>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:*</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" class="1245-required" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" class="1433-required" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color*:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Orange" class="1433[]-required"/>Orange
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Blue" class="1433[]-required"/>Blue
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Green" class="1433[]-required"/>Green
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="None" class="valuetext" class="1834-required">None
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="All" class="valuetext" class="1834-required">All
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset><br>
<fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
                <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc Info Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1302" name="1302">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1303" name="1303" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>


</form>​
```

**my jquery here:**

```
$("#section-11").hide();
$("#section-12").hide();
$("#section-13").hide();
$("#section-1011").hide();

var projtype = new Array(
        {value : 'Cars', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-11'},
        {value : 'Planes', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-12'},
        {value : 'Boats', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-13'}
    );
$("select#1169").on('change',function () {
var thisVal = $(this).val();
 var sect_id ="";
     //$('fieldset[id!="mainSection"]').hide();
    $(projtype).each(function() {
$(this.sect_id).hide();
        if(this.value == thisVal) {
        $(this.sect_id).show();
        }
    });        
});

$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function() {
    var requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find('input[class*="-required"], select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() {
      return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";  
    });
    if ($requiredButEmpty.length) {
        $requiredButEmpty.each(function () {

            $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
        });
    }
    return !$requiredButEmpty.length;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have a typo.

```
var requiredButEmpty
```

needs to be

```
var $requiredButEmpty
```

Also, you can't really use that one function to check checkboxes and radio buttons because these you would need to see if they are checked or selected. Checking the value of these would not work.

Comment: wow, can't believe I overlooked those - well yes I can.  Thank you and that made all the difference. I've updated the my fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe out of your code context, but it could answer your question:

If using html5, you can just add a `required` attribute to your required inputs, like this:

```
<input type="text" required />
```

In your jQuery just validate them:

```
var errorList = [];

function validateRequiredFields(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("required") && $(this).val() === ""){
            errorList.push($(this).attr("name"));
        }
    });
    showErrors();
}

function showErrors(){
    $("#holdErrMsg").html("Please fill in this fields: " + errorList.toString());
    errorList = [];
}
```

Call validateRequiredFields before submitting.

In addition, if you want to match specific patterns (i.e. numbers only) you can add a `pattern` attribute to the input (in case it's text type) and attempt to match the regexp. I.e. a 10 digit phone number field:

```
<input type="text" required pattern="^[0-9]{0,10}$" />
```

Then your validateRequiredFields() would be something like:

```
function validateRequiredFields(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("required")){
            if($(this).attr("pattern") && !(new RegExp($(this).attr("pattern"))).test($(this).val())){
                errorList.push($(this).attr("name"));
            }
            else if($(this).val() === ""){
                errorList.push($(this).attr("name"));
            }
        }
    });
    showErrors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Secondly, your selector is finding 0 matches, I would go with:

http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/jVktq/

Your example fiddle has 0 classes with the required class. Once I added that, your code worked fine.

Comment: Tejs - when u say I have no required classes - the fields that are listed as required are like this [<select id="1433" class="1433-required" name="1433">] so I am looking for the field within the visible FS that ends in -required.

Comment: In your fiddle, none of the fields had a `*-required` class name.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what code you guys are running on your fiddles because both of the fiddles linked above error out when I try to run them.

Just to begin with as code cleanup :

```
if ($requiredButEmpty.length) {
    $requiredButEmpty.each(function () {

        $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
    });
}
```

isn't really necessary. It can just be:

```
    requiredButEmpty.each(function () {
        $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
    });
```

as it won't run any more than 0 times if there is no length.

***Also please note that I have removed the $ in front of requiredButEmpty as you are returning a jquery object you don't need to keep referencing it with $(var) (Unless that was simply a typo then n/m).

Also i don't know what this line is for

```
    return !$requiredButEmpty.length;
```

As it is an anonymous function being called from an event handler it is not necessary to return anything, you're not returning it to anywhere.

---

I think lu1s has it pretty much correct. The only slight variation that being if you aren't using html5, or you know you'll have users who don't use browsers that support it, you can just manually put a class="required" for them and then just search for:

```
$('.required').forEach(function(){
    if ($(this).val==='')
        --push to array
});
```